# How do you run a portion of a python script that requires superuser privileges, while the rest does not?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gnome, xlib

I'm trying to make a script that will detect the color of a pixel, and have a keybind (say F5) to trigger this action.

The pixel scan portion can be done with something like this (put together from what I've found):

```
from Xlib import display, X
from PIL import Image

dsp = display.Display()
root = dsp.screen().root

def getPixelColor(x, y):
    raw = root.get_image(x, y, 1, 1, X.ZPixmap, 0xffffff)
    if isinstance(raw.data,str):
        bytes=raw.data.encode()
    else:
        bytes=raw.data
    image = Image.frombytes("RGB", (1, 1), bytes, "raw", "BGRX")
    color = '%02x%02x%02x' % image.getpixel((0,0))

    return color
```

This works, however when I want to combine it with the keyboard capturing portion of it:

```
import keyboard

def detect_key(event):
    color = getPixelColor(100,100)

    # Code that will do something with the color would go here 

    return False

keyboard.on_press_key("F5", detect_key)
keyboard.wait()
```

... it complains that `keyboard` requires root. If I run it as a superuser, then Xlib cannot connect to the x11 display.

How can I run the script to use both parts?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, with Gnome and X11.

Comment: what about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741131/how-to-launch-linux-elevated-privileges-window-from-python

Comment: Why not use `Xlib` to detect key events instead of using the `keyboard` module?

Comment: Can you post the error message you receive?